# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized''

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed a sample Power BI dashboard in a WPF application following the sample project and sort of tutorial from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/27/integrate-power-bi-dashboards-reports-and-tiles-into-a-wpf-application/). When I launch the app, I have to enter my password to authenticate myself and when it tries to get the list of my Power BI workspaces with the `getAppWorkspacesList()` I am getting this error message

> Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: 'Operation returned an invalid
>   status code 'Unauthorized''

Can someone please help in pointing out why this error is occuring? I tried to look into the details of the error, but I am not understanding what could be causing the issue. I was able to embed a dashboard in a .Net Web App without an issue, so I don't think the problem is in my Power BI or Azure Directory account.

[image]

```
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
Uri redirectUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"]);
private static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

private static string graphResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResourceId"];
private AuthenticationContext authContext = null;

TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = null;
string Token = null;
string ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com";



public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TC);
}


private void getAppWorkspacesList()
{
    using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
    {
        appWorkSpacesList.ItemsSource = client.Groups.GetGroups().Value.Select(g => new workSpaceList(g.Name, g.Id));                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, I assumed that you are using the Access token for Power BI users (user owns data) approach. I would recommend you use https://jwt.io/ to decode the access_token after successfully invoked `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync`. Make sure the `aud` is `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api` and check the permissions scope property `scp`.

For [Get Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243842.aspx), the required scope would look as follows:

> **Required scope**: Group.Read.All or Group.ReadWrite.All or Workspace.Read.All or Workspace.ReadWrite.All

You could also use fiddler or postman to simulate the request against the get groups endpoint with the access_token received in your WPF application to narrow down this issue.

Moreover, you could follow [Register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app) to check your Azure AD app and make sure the required delegated permissions to **Power BI Service (Microsoft.Azure.AnalysisServices)** API have been correctly configured.

Comment: Yeah, for the first point, since OP has a `graphResourceId`, it suggests the resource id could be wrong.

Comment: The related code sample is https://github.com/rreilly70/PowerBIEmbedded-Native-WPFBrowser/blob/master/PowerBIEmbedded-Native-WPFBrowser/MainWindow.xaml.cs. The configuration in the code sample is correct, but op still need to check the retrieved access token.

Comment: @Bruc Thank you. It was an issue of permissions in my Azure AD. After hours of struggling with editing the code, I just decided to grant permissions for all the categories under the Power BI Service API and it worked.

Comment: @BruceChen: Tailing your answer, scp property isnt available in token. Is it the problem with token generation?

Answer (score 3):

We got the same error when we use app owns data approach. The way to solve that is described [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/401-when-accessing-any-Power-BI-API-endpoints/m-p/336493#M9954).

Basically, the way to get access token documented in Microsoft [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-for-non-power-bi-users-app-owns-data) does not work. We end up making a REST API call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token and post the following data:

- grant_type: password
- scope: openid
- resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
- client_id: APPLICATION_ID
- client_secret: APPLICATION_SECRET
- username: USER_ID
- password: USER_PASSWORD

You will get a JSON back and then you can get the access_token which will be used when creating power bi client like this:

```
    var mTokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken, "Bearer");
    using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com"), mTokenCredentials))
```

I hope this can help someone. [This](https://bitbucket.org/omnistream/powerbi-api-example/src/master/) is the original post.